# Is there a universal 'after-theme-load' hook?

Tags: init-file, hooks, themes

I would like to set several face variables for use with any theme in my personal init-file. Is there a hook I could use to insure it is theme independent?

Comment: I am not sure about  a hook that will have the right timing, but would it work for you to simply set the face variables in your init file *after* the call to `load-theme`? I have done something similar in the past because some themes would color the `fill-column-indicator` in a way that made it almost invisible, so I just set it to always be a particular color regardless of theme.

Comment: @elethan that works just fine. I assumed `load-theme` worked like a mode and required a hook. It make sense, the theme is global between modes and sets all variables when loaded. I was worried about setting an undefined variable, though I was just over thinking it. Could you reenter it in as answer?

Comment: Please post the answer yourself - it looks like elethan will not be posting it. And then please accept the posted answer.

Comment: Perhaps you would like to submit an enhancement request to add an `after-load-them-hook`? Use `M-x report-emacs-bug` to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `after-theme-load-hook`. The theme is loaded directly after `(load-theme 'theme-name)`. Simply modify the desired theme variables after the `load-theme` function call.

Comment: This is not a satisfactory solution IMO. If you do this interactively in your emacs session, you are going to have to use the advice system to automatically set variables after load-theme is called. Usually, and certainly in this case, the need to use the advice system is evidence of a missing hook.

Comment: It seems overboard to define advice around load-theme just to get a few customized fonts. Though I agree, if load theme is called interactively the customizations would be overridden. But I do not change themes often and it has not been an issue.

Comment: The missing of a vim like autocmd (I am talking about `autocmd ColorScheme *`) is really saddening.