# Faces not set immediately after load-theme

Tags: hooks, faces, themes, advice, emacs-daemon

I'm trying to set the faces of [highlight-indent-guides](https://github.com/DarthFennec/highlight-indent-guides) automatically whenever a new theme is loaded by making small adjustments to the background color of the default face. I have everything working [here](http://ivanmalison.github.io/dotfiles/#highlightindentguides), but I've been forced to resort to the following horrible hack:

```
(defun imalison:set-highlight-indent-guides-faces-load-theme (&rest args)
  (if (face-background 'default)
      (imalison:set-highlight-indent-guides-faces)
    (run-at-time "1 sec" nil 'imalison:set-highlight-indent-guides-faces-load-theme)))

(advice-add 'load-theme
            :after 'imalison:set-highlight-indent-guides-faces-load-theme)
```

The reason the timer is needed is because `(face-background 'default)` is nil immediately after the call to `load-theme`, even though it is properly set a few seconds later. As I mention in [the issue](https://github.com/DarthFennec/highlight-indent-guides/issues/9) that I filed against [highlight-indent-guides](https://github.com/DarthFennec/highlight-indent-guides), I suspect that `load-theme` might rely on a callback somewhere when setting face values, which would explain why the face is not set when the function returns. Does anyone who is more familiar with emacs' theme system know what is going on here? Is there a reason there is [no `after-load-theme` hook](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/22686/is-there-a-universal-after-theme-load-hook)?

Comment: Not sure what the problem is, but I believe the proper way of modifying a theme face is using `custom-theme-set-faces` rather than changing the face directly with `set-face-background`.

Comment: This only seems to happen when I start emacs in daemon without a frame. If I start emacs normally, everything is fine.